# angled snapping/mirror/ of instances?

Tags: mirror, snapping, instances

I was wondering if their is a simple solution to snapping instances of say 4 objects, or mirroring them to the other side.

When I have done this, the snapping of the group of the array of 4, is hard to see how to snap it all, rather than one at a time.

I tried various ways, and got the face snapping to work in singles but not grouped.

How does someone get instances to mirror, at angles of incline.   The object did mirror, but in the same angle, not the opposite?

I have deleted it now, but would still like the answer. I tried to put the instance on parent to snapping object also. With origin changes also.  I must be missing something simple.

I would have used snap to face view, but the numpad options set me to angles not on the correct angle either.

[image: the rotation will not keep the snap to face, and the mirror does not mirror exact opposite]

the rotation snapping seems to be sorted, but not mirror?

Comment: Hello :). Would you mind adding some images to illustrate your question? My imagination isn't what it used to be...